# Scilab does not free memory after clearing workspace and reducing stacksize. Why?

Tags: memory, ram, scilab, stack-size

I use Scilab 5.5.0 on a Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit system. I increase stacksize for filtering tasks with higer memory amount: `stacksize("1e7")`. Then scilab takes up to 700 MB memory. Afer deleting all variales in the workspace by typing `clear` the memory usage does not decrease. Even `stacksize("min")` does not help.

This memory utilization slows down my whole system. What could avoid this?
I want Scilab to reserve memory just for the execution time. After all calculations are done it should free the used memory for other processes. It this possible?